# Python: using a method of a class imported from another file

Tags: python

so I'm trying to use a method from an imported class, but I get an error. Here is a reproducible example:

file1.py

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, A1, A2):
        self.A1 = A1
        self.A2 = A2

    def add_A1_A2(self):
        print(self.A1+self.A2)
```

file2.py

```
from file1 import A
A1=1
A2=2
A(A1, A2).add_A1_A2()
```

I get an error: `name 'A1' is not defined`

Comment: It looks like you fixed your bug in your most recent edit. Do you still have a problem?

Comment: The code shown now works fine. The return value is 3.

Comment: Yes I still do have the same problem  `6     def add_A1_A2(self):
----> 7         print(self.A1+self.A2)

NameError: name 'A1' is not defined`

Comment: Your previous code would not, indeed, work, because `add_A1_A2` had two free variables `A1` and `A2` that wouldn't resolve to any variable visible to it.

Comment: yes @chepner I was intending to say that this code is the one not working, and it still is for me. it's curious!

Comment: As you can see in the error I have `print(self.A1+self.A2)`

Comment: How, exactly, are you running it? You don't appear to have re-loaded the module after editing `file1.py`. The old code is being run, but the error message is constructed using the new version of the file. Hint: the code in the error message doesn't *have* the name `A1`, only an attribute of `self` named `A1`.

Comment: I run the whole code starting from: `from file1 import A`

Comment: Thanks everyone, as was indicated by @Cireo it was a problem in the cache, when I restarted the IDE it worked fine!

Answer (score 3):

Works for me =P.  Check that you don't have cached `.pyc` files around.

```
$ cat file1.py 
class A:
    def __init__(self, A1, A2):
        self.A1 = A1
        self.A2 = A2

    def add_A1_A2(self):
        print(self.A1+self.A2)
```

```
$ cat file2.py 
from file1 import A
A1=1
A2=2
A(A1, A2).add_A1_A2()
```

```
$ python3.7 file2.py 
3
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Sorry, what should I do exactly?